# Two Ubuntu Machines cannot access each other's shares anymore

Tags: networking, samba, shared-folders

I have two Ubuntu laptops, both running 14.04 "Trusty Tahr". At one point, they were both able to access each other's shared folders. However, something happened when I was trying to add a third Ubuntu 14.04 machine into the mix, and now none of the computers can see each other on Nautilis -> Browse Network (or Dolphin, for that matter).

I have Samba installed and updated on both machines. They're all on the same WAN, and they're all configured to the "PAWSHARE" workgroup. (Resetting to "WORKGROUP" does not fix it.) When I updated Samba today, I went ahead and overwrote the old configuration files, just in case something borked, and reconfigured the workgroup.

Yet, I still see nothing. I've browsed Google for hours over the past few weeks, trying to solve this, and yet nothing works. At last check, I can ping one laptop from another successfully.

I'm at the end of my rope, now. Help?

(FYI: Not a duplicate of "Unable to connect to Samba share folders - desperation ahead." I don't have a "server/client" setup, nor am I particular interested in doing so. I just want the regular computers to see each other's shared folders.)

Comment: If Samba shares aren't necessary (just access to the other systems' folders is needed in the file browser), you can use SFTP.

Comment: No, I need Samba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it. It is a bit slow in updating the network (the machines are appearing, but it takes a few minutes), but I got it figured out.

There was a misconfiguration in one the files. I'm not sure how it got misconfigured, but correcting it fixed the issue.

```
sudo gedit /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

Change

> hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns

to

> hosts:          files wins dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]